# Data.table: function using the paste0 cols and lapply feature rewrites input?

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have created a function to edit values of selected columns in a data.table `a`. The columns are selected based on the entries of a second data.table `b`.

The selection of columns is done by matching the values in `b$names` to the column names of `a`, with one column of `a` being selected for each match made.

The matching columns are then updated using the `paste0(cols,"") := lapply(.SD, compute, x2 = b[i,vals])` feature of the data.table package.

Here is the code I am using:

```r
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

a <- data.table(A = seq(1, 10), mean_one = rnorm(10, 4, 5), mean_two = rnorm(10, 0, 4), mean_three = rnorm(10, 7, 1), sd_one = rnorm(10, 2, 1), sd_two = rnorm(10, 1,0.5), sd_three = rnorm(10, 5, 1))
b <- data.table(names = c("one", "two", "three"), vals = c(50, 40, 30))

# Display a before applying convert function
a

convert <- function(data1, data2){
  # Internal copy of input data1 (introduced this line after first noticing problem but changes nothing)
  output <- data1
  
  # Define internal function to apply to columns
  compute <- function(x1,x2){
    x1/x2*100
  }
  
  #Loop to go through all ines in data2 and apply compute to them
  for(i in 1:nrow(data2)){
    # Identify columns that match of group entry
    col_nums <- str_which(colnames(output), pattern = b[i,names])
    cols <- colnames(output[,..col_nums])
    
    # Update BD columns by applying get_BDpercent to group
    output <- output[, paste0(cols, "") := lapply(.SD, compute, x2 = data2[i,vals]), .SDcols = cols]
  }
  output
}

c <- convert(a,b)

a
```

Applying the function to create a new object `c` works fine but somehow `a` gets modified too:
`a` before applying the function:

```
     A  mean_one   mean_two mean_three   sd_one     sd_two sd_three
 1:  1  5.401716  2.3178453   7.861245 2.242470 1.38388160 5.973074
 2:  2  6.297607 -5.3536197   8.129933 3.059719 0.82876696 3.888044
 3:  3 -7.335733  2.7596386   6.925848 3.052197 0.83010216 4.467223
 4:  4 13.102340  5.2097568   6.833323 1.695432 1.11115086 4.925649
 5:  5  4.027482 -3.3134371   9.007320 2.478962 1.09693094 3.951823
 6:  6  9.870239  2.7126299   6.162253 1.223240 1.55348307 5.051808
 7:  7  7.820498 -0.8919731   4.783220 1.340520 1.47370370 3.268912
 8:  8 -2.641131 -9.3359900   6.538014 1.947230 0.73272735 4.299064
 9:  9 -1.128654 -2.1083705   8.170297 1.286314 0.07326959 5.110170
10: 10 -2.255471 -2.5927778   7.062032 3.714906 0.40010323 6.131127
```

`a` after applying the function (same as `c`, the desired output):

```
     A   mean_one   mean_two mean_three   sd_one   sd_two sd_three
 1:  1  10.803432   5.794613   26.20415 4.484940 3.459704 19.91025
 2:  2  12.595214 -13.384049   27.09978 6.119439 2.071917 12.96015
 3:  3 -14.671467   6.899097   23.08616 6.104394 2.075255 14.89074
 4:  4  26.204680  13.024392   22.77774 3.390865 2.777877 16.41883
 5:  5   8.054964  -8.283593   30.02440 4.957924 2.742327 13.17274
 6:  6  19.740477   6.781575   20.54084 2.446479 3.883708 16.83936
 7:  7  15.640997  -2.229933   15.94407 2.681040 3.684259 10.89637
 8:  8  -5.282262 -23.339975   21.79338 3.894460 1.831818 14.33021
 9:  9  -2.257308  -5.270926   27.23432 2.572629 0.183174 17.03390
10: 10  -4.510942  -6.481945   23.54011 7.429812 1.000258 20.43709
```

While this would not be a problem if I never got back to `a`, this function is included in a Shiny app and getting back modifications like this one will mess it up.

Is there something I am missing? Or maybe there is something I don't understand about the way these columns are updated. My guess is that the issue has to do with how data.table works.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want `a` modified you should copy the data in your function. e.g. `output <- copy(data1)`

Comment: So simple! Thanks a bunch!!
But I am curious as to why the update of columns in the local function environment on `output` is carried into the global environment on the input data.table.
Why are there any operations carried out on `a` to begin with?

Comment: No prob, check out this vignette on data.table reference semantics for more info. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html).